# com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraPreview import is greyed out

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to essentially combine the video overlay sample code and the point cloud sample code (both java) on android studio. My goal is to have the point cloud sit on top of the live feed from the camera. When I go to try and merge the code together everything except the TangoCameraPreview class will work. Android studio says that the import is unused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Travis, can you give more info on how you merged two code together?

Comment: What I have done so far is made a new class in the PointCloud Java sample file that has the sample code from the VideoOverlay Java Sample. I know that in the imported libraries of the PointCloud Java file the TangoCameraPreview class isn't included so I have determined that to be the issue. I resolved that issue. My current issue is still apart of this question though. I can't get the two classses to run at the same time so that the video overlay will replace the grid background of the PointCloud Java Sample. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Travis, if you want to achieve this, you cannot reused the TangoCameraPreview class, instead, you should use the texture id you get form API, and display it with you own texture renderer in the gl context.. I haven't test this myself, but I bet this will work..

Comment: I appreciate the help Jason, I am very new to Android Programming and I am not sure where to begin with your solution. If you know of an example or something that can push me down that direction I would greatly appreciate it.